# Incoming meetings requests aren't showing up in my Inbox. Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

When someone sends me a meeting request, it doesn't send me a new email with the request.  It just pops up immediately in my Reminders Window.  I cannot figure out why.  I have checked and my client is not set to auto-accept the meeting request (`Calendar Options -> Resource Scheduling ---> Automatically Accecpt Meeting Requests` is NOT checked).

Is there something I'm missing?  I don't even accept the meeting and the meeting organizer says I haven't responded or accepted the meeting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The emails were grouped by message class, so all the meeting requests were being pushed to the bottom.

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, 11 years later +1. I did this and was mystified. I am sure the same reason is causing many others to be confused, like [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_o365b/outlook-2013-meeting-notifications-not-showing-in/d5b64a98-0e6d-49e0-a2ab-8e9c9f53d18b) with hundreds of people asking the same question.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many [posts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_o365b/outlook-desktop-app-calendar-invites-not-received/5c617105-84ef-413b-9a7a-324abb6ef867) about this problem, and few have a solution. The existing answer here from a decade ago helped me, but here are some other possibilities for those who arrive here in the future:

1. You might have delegates setup.
2. Check if autoaccept is turned on
3. Make sure there are no rules moving out meeting invites.

Easy steps to fix the view in *Outlook for Microsoft 365 16.0.x*:

When in Inbox,

```
 View menu --> Current View --> Reset Current View
```